# How to create a Python df from a .csv using a defined function

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I'm trying to produce a function to ultimately read in .csv files and create a df.

I've written the following code which imports the file and creates the df (df_input) but I can't reference df_input outside the function.

```
def combine_files(data_file):
   df_input = pd.read_csv(data_file)
   return df_input
```

When I action the function with the following code:

```
combine_files('datasets/202105.csv')
```

It returns the contents of df_input but if I try to reference df_input outside the function I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'df_input' is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: try data = combine_files('datasets/202105.csv') and then call data variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result from `combine_files` to a variable.

```
df = combine_files('datasets/202105.csv')
```

Then you can use `df`

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_files(data_file):
   df_input = pd.read_csv(data_file)
   return df_input

data = combine_files('datasets/202105.csv')

print(data)
```